# Does the set of positive definite kernels on some set X form a ring?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, kernels

Given some non-empty set $X$, does the set of positive definite kernels on $K_X$ form a ring with pointwise addition and multiplication. I am convinced it does not as surely if $k \in K_X$ then we would require that $-k \in K_X$ also, which I don't think is true?

I ask because Hagan (the user) seems to think it does in this question: [The Polynomial Kernel](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31030/the-polynomial-kernel)

If not, does it even form an abelian group with respect to any other operation? Or better yet, a ring?

Comment: It isn't a ring: Hagen's statement was not quite correct. It is closed under pointwise addition, multiplication by positive reals, and pointwise product.

Comment: I think that this question, while natural, should really have been a comment on the old question (but I appreciate that as a new user you can't yet leave comments)

Comment: Thank you, yes I had tried to leave a comment but was unable.

Comment: It's an abelian group for every abelian group structure... every nonempty set carries an abelian group structure (and even a ring structure). So "any other operation" is too open-ended, since it's not really interesting if the ring structure is unrelated to the way this set was defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it answered (cw):

> It's not stable under taking $x\mapsto -x$ so is not a ring, as it's not a group under addition.